# javafx - table dosn't update if I change a property of the ObservableList

Tags: javafx, refresh, tableview, pojo, observablelist

I have this item:

```
    public class Person {
    private SimpleStringProperty name;

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty(){
        if(this.name==null){
            this.name=new SimpleStringProperty();
        }
        return this.name;
    }

    public final void setName(String value){
        nameProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public Person(String value){
        setName(value);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.getName();
    }
}
```

and a table:

```
TableColumn nomePersona = new TableColumn("NOME")
nomePersona.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("name"));
nomePersona.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());     
table.getColumns().setAll(nomePersona);        
lista = FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList();
lista.addAll(new Person("uno"),new Person("due"),new Person("tre"));
table.setItems(lista);
```

I also have a button than add an item:

```
private void addPerson(ActionEvent event) {
        Person p = new Person(text.getText());
        lista.add(0, p);
    }
```

and another that modify the text of the first row:

```
    private void modifyPerson(ActionEvent event) {
        lista.get(0).setName(TEST_TF.getText());
//        lista.remove(0);
//        lista.add(0, new Person(TEST_TF.getText()));
    }
```

I can see the modification on the first row if I update the text pressing the modifyPerson button but if before I add a new item pressing the addPerson button the table doesn't refresh anymore.
I print the observable list and the item is correctly update but the cell stays with the old value.
The only way to get the modification is remove and add a new item (see the 2 commented rows on modifyPerson()

Thanks in advance.

here the complete code:
**File Person.java**

```
package table;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {
    private SimpleStringProperty name;

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty(){
        if(this.name==null){
            this.name=new SimpleStringProperty();
        }
        return this.name;
    }

    public final void setName(String value){
        nameProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public Person(String value){
        setName(value);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.getName();
    }
}
```

File **FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
package table;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private ObservableList<Person> lista;

    @FXML
    private Button btn_add;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Person> combo;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfld_textAdd;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> tbl_table;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_upd;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfld_textUpdate;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_del;

    @FXML
    private void act_addItem(ActionEvent event) {
        Person p = new Person(tfld_textAdd.getText());
        lista.add(0, p);
        System.out.println(lista.toString());
    }

    @FXML
    private void act_updItem(ActionEvent event) {
        lista.get(0).setName(tfld_textUpdate.getText());
//        lista.remove(0);
//        lista.add(0, new Person(tfld_textUpdate.getText()));
        System.out.println(lista.toString());
    }

    @FXML
    private void act_delItem(ActionEvent event) {
                lista.remove(lista.size()-1);
        System.out.println(lista.toString());
    }
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        TableColumn nomePersona = new TableColumn("NOME");
        nomePersona.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("name"));
        nomePersona.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());     
        tbl_table.getColumns().setAll(nomePersona);
        lista = FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList();
        lista.addAll(new Person("uno"),new Person("due"),new Person("tre"));
        tbl_table.setItems(lista);
        combo.setItems(lista);
        lista.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                System.out.println("INVALIDATION");            
                System.out.println(observable.toString());
            }
        });
        lista.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>() {
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) {
                System.out.println("LIST CHANGER");
                while (c.next()) {
                  if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                      for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                           System.out.println("Permutato");
                      }
                  } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                           System.out.println("Updatato: ");
                  } else {
                      for (Person remitem : c.getRemoved()) {
                          System.out.println("rimosso: " + remitem.getName());
                      }
                      for (Person additem : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                          System.out.println("addizionato: " + additem.getName());
                      }
                  }
              }
            }
        });              
    }
}
```

Here the file **Table.java**

```
package table;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Table extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and than the FXML **FXMLDocumen.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="409.0" prefWidth="463.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="table.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btn_add" layoutX="175.0" layoutY="10.0" onAction="#act_addItem" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="ADD ITEM 0" /><ComboBox fx:id="combo" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="94.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="200.0" /><TextField fx:id="tfld_textAdd" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0" /><TableView fx:id="tbl_table" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="123.0" prefHeight="275.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="124.0" /><Button fx:id="btn_upd" layoutX="232.0" layoutY="124.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#act_updItem" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="221.0" text="REWRITE ITEM 0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="232.0" /><TextField fx:id="tfld_textUpdate" layoutX="232.0" layoutY="94.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="221.0" text="aaa" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="232.0" /><Button fx:id="btn_del" layoutX="298.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#act_delItem" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="DEL ITEM 0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: This worked fine when I tested it. Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, sure, I just edited and I cut/paste the files; try this sequence please: 1) press "REWRITE ITEM 0" button, you will see the text on item 0 changes. 2) write "ccc" on the upper-left text field and press "ADD ITEM 0" button. 3) press again "REWRITE ITEM 0" button and you will notice that the table is not updated, but in the consolle you can see the observable is ok. NOTE: if you don't add any item and you just update the value everything work fine.

Comment: Still worked just fine, using the order of operations you specified. What version of Java/JavaFX are you using?

Comment: Thanks James! So -> System.out.println("Java:..... " + System.getProperty("java.version")); gives me Java:..... 1.8.0_20-ea and System.out.println("JavaFX:... " + com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion()); gives me JavaFX:... 8.0.20-ea-b14. I tested with another computer with 1.8.0_05 and JavaFX:... 8.0.5-b14 and is working.

Comment: Also with the new update I just installed works: 1.8.0_20 and 8.0.20-b26. So my versione had a bug. So, this is fixed but... the problem still happen on ComboBox: please try this: 1) launch the program - 2) press "REWITE ITEM 0". 2) open the combo and you will see at item 0 the value is updated. 3) insert "bbb" on the textfield above the rewrite button and press the "REWITE ITEM 0" button. the table is correctly updated but if you open the combo the first item is still the old value, but if you select him the combo correctly show the new value. THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR TIME!